# Как идентифицировать устройство, чтобы пользователь мог получить в настройках устройства свой идентификатор?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Есть одна сторона которая имеет данные об устройстве, имей и прочее прочее

И есть приложение в которое надо зашить определенный алгоритм уникальное идентификатора, чтобы сторона могла знать этот идентификатор и связать с ним данные какие-либо.

В случае imei это очень легко решается, сторона imei знает и может формировать легко привязку данных к этому imei. Каким образом можно зашить уникальный идентификатор приложения и при этом чтобы пользователь устройства мог узнать этот идентифкатор?

Работать должно на android 10+ поэтому imei и серийный номер отпадают.

Comment: А чем тогда imei не подходит?

Comment: Можно mac например взять.

Comment: @nick_n_a imei с android 10+ нельзя получить

Comment: @nick_n_a mac адрес недоступен в настройках

Comment: Не очень понятны цели данного мероприятия. Вы хотите использовать этот идентификатор как некий токен/ключ для шифрования или что? Можете пояснить сам use-case такой ситуации? И что это за *сторона* - это что сервер, другое приложение или что?

Comment: @Barmaley другая сторона это компания у которой 20к устройств и все устройства распределены по магазинам. Данные идентифицирующее это устройство imei,serial number и т.д выписаны в файл-табличку. И эта компания хочет за каким-то уникальным идентификатором закреплять название магазина. Так вот с imei эта проблема решается до андроид 10, после 10 андроида ищу решение за что можно зацепиться)

Comment: *>Работать должно на android 10+ поэтому imei и серийный номер отпадают.*

Что это означает? Почему в Android 10+ нельзя получить IMEI? Или я опять чего-то не понимаю?

[getImei()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getImei()) - разве не работает в Android 10+?

Comment: @Barmaley getImei() работает только при наличии READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/device-identifiers

Comment: @ermak0ff и что? Запросить разрешение и получить его - в чем проблема? Это же стандартная история...

Comment: @Barmaley c данным типом разрешений не все так просто, "запросить" его не получится.

Comment: Почитал - вижу, что его могут по сути запросить только вендоры и опсосы - согласен, это проблема.

Answer (score -1):

Если требуется получить идентификатор, который обязательно должен быть в настройках устройства, то есть способ это сделать без root прав - использовать mac адрес. Для этого требуется сделать приложение `Device Owner` с помощью adb команды `adb shell dpm set-device-owner`, а затем использовать метод [getWifiMacAddress()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#getWifiMacAddress(android.content.ComponentName))

Если же идентификатор допустимо показывать пользователю только внутри самого приложения, есть следующие способы:

1 способ - если не требуется сохранение идентификатора между переустановками приложения.
В этом случае в соответствии с [Best practices for unique identifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids) рекомендуется использовать [GUID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID):

> Use a Firebase installation ID (FID) or a privately stored GUID whenever possible for all other use cases, except for payment fraud prevention and telephony. For the vast majority of non-ads use cases, an FID or GUID should be sufficient.

GUID позволит обеспечить достаточную уникальность вашего идентификатора:

> Хотя уникальность каждого отдельного GUID не гарантируется, общее
> количество уникальных ключей настолько велико (2128 или 3,4028×1038),
> что вероятность того, что в мире будут независимо сгенерированы два
> совпадающих ключа, крайне мала

Сгенерировать GUID можно так:

```
val uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

Однако хранить идентификатор придется самостоятельно. Вы можете сохранить идентификатор, например в `Shared Preferences`. В таком случае когда вам нужен идентификатор, проверяете, есть ли он в `Shared Preferences`. Если его там нет, генерируете и сохраняете.

2 способ - если требуется, чтобы идентификатор сохранялся после переустановки приложения. Используйте `ANDROID_ID`. На Android ниже версии 8.0 этот идентификатор генерировался, когда пользователь впервые настраивал устройство и не отличался для разных приложений. На Android версии 8.0 и выше, этот идентификатор для каждого приложения генерируется отдельный, но остается, если приложение было переустановлено. Однако идентификатор сбрасывается после OTA обновления или сброса к заводским настройкам. Подробнее в [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID)

Получить `ANDROID_ID` можно так:

```
val uniqueID = Settings.Secure.getString(applicationContext.contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)
```

Comment: ни один из ваших примеров не подходит т.к нельзя их посмотреть в настройках устройства)

Comment: добавил еще один способ, возможно подойдет для вашего сценария

Comment: ANDROID_ID - так же нельзя посмотреть в настройках устройства)

Comment: я про способ с использование mac адреса, который добавил в начало ответа